# Quote about classical music during the Industrial Revolution

Tags: classical-music

I know, there's a (famous) composer who said that classical music during the industrial revolution should sound louder, because there was more noise (from machines) to be "good".

I want to know who said that, and the actual quote with his own words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is vague enough that I'm not sure I have the precise answer, but it seems to me that it may be referring to the work *[The Art of Noises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Noises)* (1913) by Luigi Russolo.

The original is in Italian, but there's an [English translation here](http://www.artype.de/Sammlung/pdf/russolo_noise.pdf). A couple of choice quotes getting at theme:

> In antiquity, life was nothing but silence. Noise was really not born before the 19th century, with the advent of machinery. Today noise reigns supreme over human sensibility. ...we are approaching noise-sound. This revolution of music is paralleled by the increasing proliferation of machinery sharing in human labor. In the pounding atmosphere of great cities as well as in the formerly silent countryside, machines create today such a large number of varied noises that pure sound, with its littleness and its monotony, now fails to arouse any emotion.

and

> ...music has developed into a search for a more complex polyphony and a greater variety of instrumental tones and coloring. It has tried to obtain the most complex succession of dissonant chords, thus preparing the ground for Musical Noise. This evolution toward noise-sound is only possible today.